# when i execute "npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli" ,what hardhat exactly did?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, react

for example,the deploy.js like this:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  const XxxNFT= await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("XxxNft");
  const xxxNFT= await RoboPunksNFT.deploy();
  await xxxNFT.deployed();

  console.log('XxxNft deployed to :',XxxNFT.address);
}
  main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`, hardhat deploys your script to the goerli network. It does so by getting an instance of the `XxxNft` contract and deploy it to the goerli network. Once it's successfully deployed, a message `RoboPunksNFT deployed to : XxxNFT.address` is printed onto the console indicating the deployment is successful. If the deployment fails, the error is caught and the process exits.

Answer (score 0):

I found your mistake,after you get contract from `getContractFactory` you should deploy your contract from the contract that you get, and you get contract as "XxxNFT", so you need deploy "XxxNFT" here's example for your code:

```
const XxxNFT= await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("XxxNft");

const xxxNFT= await XxxNFT.deploy();
await xxxNFT.deployed();

// now you can show your contract adddress from xxx.NFT:

console.log('XxxNft deployed to :',xxxNFT.address);
```